# NGINX ingress doesn't work unless there is a ingress resource at root path

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, azure-aks, nginx-ingress, nginx-config

The kubernetes NGINX ingress controller doesn't work unless there is a ingress resource defined at the root path.

If my ingress resource has a path with rewrite and without path at root("/") I'm not able to reach the application with the route "http://ingressip/node/order. But If I add the below path to the same ingress, I'm able to access.

```
      - path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: aks-helloworld-one
            port:
              number: 80
```

my-ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: nodeapp-ingress-direct
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /node(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: nodeapp
            port:
              number: 80
```

I'm expecting NGINX default backend 404 if there is no path at root("/") which is not happening. I'm not able to reach the ingress at http://ingressip at all.

What am I missing?

Environment details:
Provider: AKS
Kubernetes version: 1.26.3
NGINX Chart: Installed through helm version 4.7.0
NGINX App Version: 1.8.0

Comment: Can you share the describe of ingress-controller service yaml?